# Error in MySQL query concerning IF statements in SELECT

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I can't figure out what is wrong with the following query:

```
SELECT   t_sh.source_file_id,
         t_sh.id,
         MAX(t_sh.master_event_id),
         IF(t_sh.content REGEXP '[;}[:space:]]break;', 'true', 'false') AS break,
         IF(t_sh.content REGEXP '[;}[:space:]]break ', 'true', 'false') AS break_label,
         IF(t_sh.content REGEXP '[;}[:space:]]continue;', 'true', 'false') AS continue,
         IF(t_sh.content REGEXP '[;}[:space:]]throw ', 'true', 'false') AS throw,
         IF(t_sh.content REGEXP '[;}[:space:]]return;', 'true', 'false') AS void_return
FROM     source_histories AS t_sh,
         (   SELECT DISTINCT source_file_id
             FROM source_histories
             WHERE content <> NULL 
                 AND content REGEXP '[;}[:space:]]break;|[;}[:space:]]break |[;}[:space:]]continue;|[;}[:space:]]throw |[;}[:space:]]return;'
         ) AS t_uniqueSFI
WHERE t_sh.source_file_id = t_uniqueSFI.source_file_id;
```

It give me the following error when run with python's MySQLdb:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
syntax to use near
'continue,\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tIF(t_sh.content REGEXP '[;}[:space:]]throw ', 'true', 'false') ' at line 6")
```

I am new to SQL, and your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem line is

```
IF(t_sh.content REGEXP '[;}[:space:]]continue;', 'true', 'false') as continue
```

continue is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) and you need to backtick something as

```
IF(t_sh.content REGEXP '[;}[:space:]]continue;', 'true', 'false') as `continue`
```

Here what happens in mysql when your query comes to this line

```
mysql> select IF(uname REGEXP '[;}[:space:]]continue;', 'true', 'false') 
AS continue from test ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for 
the right syntax to use near 'continue from test' at line 1
```

Now if I use backtick on my test table I get

```
mysql> select IF(uname REGEXP '[;}[:space:]]continue;', 'true', 'false')
 AS `continue` from test ;
+----------+
| continue |
+----------+
| false    |
| false    |
| false    |
| false    |
| false    |
| false    |
| false    |
+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I should have known to look at reserved words.